# Specify an entry array in Webpack CLI

Tags: webpack

In a config, we'd specify an entry array like so:

```
entry: [
  'polyfills',
  './src/index.js'
]
```

I was wondering if it's possible to specify this via the CLI:

```
$ webpack [opts] <entry_array?> <output>
```

To be clear, I'm referring to a single entry with an array of modules and not multiple entries (which I understand is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass all the entry points as arguments, they will be treated as a single chunk just like using an array in the config. In your case the following would create a `bundle.js` which contains both `polyfills` and `./src/index.js`:

```
webpack polyfills ./src/index.js bundle.js
```

To clear out any confusion about multiple chunks, the CLI accepts arguments in the form `<name>=<entry>`, that work just like using an object in the config. So the following would generate a `polyfills.bundle.js` and an `app.bundle.js` with the respective entry points:

```
webpack polyfills=polyfills app=./src/index.js [name].bundle.js
```

*Note: if the output is one file, webpack will complain that there is a conflict.*

For more details have a look the offical docs for [CLI without config file](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#usage-without-config-file).

Answer (score 0):

@Michael, I experienced the same issues, which I got errors to combine multiple entries into one output file. I do this in webpack-cli only for exercise.

With option two, I got,

```
npx webpack index=./src/index.js app=./src/index2.js [name].bundle.js
zsh: no matches found: [name].bundle.js
```

Option 1, it's

```
npx webpack ./src/index.js ./src/index2.js dist/bundle.js
Hash: fe5cb8d967e4e39a16b8
Version: webpack 4.32.0
Time: 105ms
Built at: 2019-05-22 11:01:35
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] multi ./src/index.js ./src/index2.js dist/bundle.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/index.js 27 bytes {0} [built]
[2] ./src/index2.js 27 bytes {0} [built]

...

ERROR in multi ./src/index.js ./src/index2.js dist/bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dist/bundle.js' in '/Users/.../Code/webpack-pitfalls'
 @ multi ./src/index.js ./src/index2.js dist/bundle.js main[2]
```